# Issues in Decryption

Tags: python, for-loop, encryption, cryptography, pixel

The input image is grayscale image broken down to 64 pixels block .The encryption function takes 64 pixels(512 bits) as input_value and 64 bit key. We split the input_value to blocks of 8 pixels value. We do 16 rounds of encryption on a set of  8 pixels . Every other function does some computation and return the value in a similar format.

When xor_8_pixels function was not used in for loop the code executed correctly for both encryption and decryption. On adding the xor_8_pixels function the decryption did not return back the original input image.(Most probably I've not positioned xor function in decryption correctly)

```
def encryption(input_value, key_value):
    keyList = create_key_list(key_value)
    result = []
    input_blocks = []
    for i in range(8):
        sub_block = (input_value[8*i:8*i+8])
        input_blocks.append(sub_block)
    # print(input_blocks)
    for i in range(16): #16 rounds
        for j in range(8):
            if j < 7:
                input_blocks[j] = xor_8_pixels(input_blocks[j], input_blocks[j - 1])
            input_blocks[j]=OwnFunctionEncrypt(input_blocks[j], keyList[i][j])
            
        if i < 15:
            input_blocks = left_shift(input_blocks)
        # print(input_blocks)
    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            result.append(input_blocks[i][j])
    return result

def decryption(input_value, key_value):
    keyList = create_key_list(key_value)
    result = []
    input_blocks = []
    for i in range(8):
        sub_block = (input_value[8*i:8*i+8])
        input_blocks.append(sub_block)
    # print(input_blocks)
    for i in range(16): # 16 rounds
        for j in range(8):
          if j < 7:
            input_blocks[j + 1] = xor_8_pixels(input_blocks[j], input_blocks[j + 1])
          input_blocks[j] = OwnFunctionDecrypt(input_blocks[j], keyList[15 - i][j])  # Decrypt
              # XOR with the next block
        if i < 15:
            input_blocks = right_shift(input_blocks) 
        # print(input_blocks)
    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            result.append(input_blocks[i][j])
    return result
```

Comment: you should probably include the `xor_8_pixels` function and anything else needed to make this a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Even without seeing your code, is likely you're putting one of the XOR's in the wrong place.  You want to do your encryption in ["CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC))".

- In encryption, you take the most recent block of output and xor with
  the next block of input before encrypting it
- In decryption, you take take the most previous ciphertext and xor it
  with the results of the current decryption.

Note that these are not symmetric.  The pictures on the Wikipedia page should make it clearer.